# How to pass variable to anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass variable `setTimeout`function and do something with that. When I alert value of `i` it shows me numbers that i did not expected. What i m doing wrong? I want log values from 1 till 8.

```
var end=8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i ++) {
       setTimeout(function (i) {
           console.log(i);   

       }, 800);
   }
```

Comment: It is correct? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Your problem is a scope problem: the `for` counter variable is called `i`, but the parameter is called `i` as well. So any value the counter-i has is overwritten as soon as you are in the parameter-i scope. Renaming either the counter or the parameter should help.

Comment: @DominikSchreiber: It's *partially* a scope problem. But just removing or renaming the `i` argument won't solve it.

Answer (score 13):

The standard way to solve this is to use a factory function:

```
var end=8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i ++) {
       setTimeout(makeResponder(i), 800);
   }

function makeResponder(index) {
    return function () {
        console.log(index);   
   };
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/udopag) | [source](http://jsbin.com/udopag/edit)

There, we *call* `makeResponder` in the loop, and it returns a function that closes over the argument passed into it (`index`) rather than the `i` variable. (Which is important. If you just removed the `i` argument from your anonymous function, your code would partially work, but all of the functions would see the value of `i` as of when they *ran*, not when they were initially scheduled; in your example, they'd all see `8`.)

---

**Update** From your comments below:

> ...will it be correct if i call it in that way `setTimeout(makeResponder(i),i*800);`?

Yes, if your goal is to have each call occur roughly 800ms later than the last one, that will work:

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oxarik) | [source](http://jsbin.com/oxarik/edit)

> I tried `setTimeout(makeResponder(i),setInterval(i));function setInterval(index) { console.log(index*800); return index*800; }` but it's not work properly

You don't use `setInterval` that way, and probably don't want to use it for this at all.

---

**Further update**: You've said below:

> I need first iteration print 8 delay 8 sec, second iteration print 7 delay 7 sec ........print 2 delay 2 sec ...print 0 delay 0 sec.

You just apply the principles above again, using a second timeout:

```
var end=8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i ++) {
       setTimeout(makeResponder(i), i * 800);
   }

function makeResponder(index) {
    return function () {
        var thisStart = new Date();
        console.log("index = " + index + ", first function triggered");
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("index = " +
                        index +
                        ", second function triggered after a further " +
                        (new Date() - thisStart) +
                        "ms delay");
        }, index * 1000);
   };
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oxarik/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/oxarik/2/edit)

I think you now have all the tools you need to take this forward.

Comment: Hi, thanks, will it be correct if i call it in that way setTimeout(makeResponder(i),i*800);? I mean this part i*800, I think it remain the same .

Comment: I tried setTimeout(makeResponder(i),setInterval(i));function setInterval(index) {
    
        console.log(index*800); 
        return index*800;
  
}  but it's not work properly

Comment: @alexeyb: I've added to the answer to address your questions above.

Comment: I got it but i need to set interval in the first iteration to 8 sec  then to 7 sec .... 3 sec according to the value that i have in index => index*1000 , but it always 1 sec.How to change it?

Comment: @alexeyb: Have you looked at the second example? (http://jsbin.com/oxarik) If so and that's not what you're trying to do, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yep  i saw it interval between output is one sec in your example... I need first iteration print 8 delay 8 sec, second iteration print 7 delay 7 sec ........print 2 delay 2 sec ...print 0 delay 0 sec..

Comment: @alexeyb: It's just a further application of `setTimeout`, surely? Updated again. I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are referring to the variable `i` some time later when your `setTimeout()` function fires and by then, the value of `i` has changed (it's gone to the end of the `for` loop.  To keep each setTimeout with it's appropriate value of `i`, you have to capture that value `i` separately for each `setTimeout()` callback.

The previous answer using a factory function does that just fine, but I find self executing functions a little easier than factory functions to type and follow, but both can work because both capture the variables you want in a closure so you can reference their static value in the setTimeout callback.

Here's how a self executing function would work to solve this problem:

```
var end=8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i ++) {
       (function (index) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               console.log(index);
           }, 800);
       })(i);
   }
```

To set the timeout delay in proportion to the value of `i`, you would do this:

```
var end=8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i ++) {
    (function (index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(index);
        }, index * 800);
    })(i);
}
```

The self executing function is passed the value of `i` and the argument inside that function that contains that value is named `index` so you can refer to `index` to use the appropriate value.

---

**Using let in ES6**

With the ES6 of Javascript (released in 2015), you can use `let` in your `for` loop and it will create a new, separate variable for each iteration of the `for` loop.  This is a more "modern" way to solve a problem like this:

```
const end = 8;
for (let i = 1; i < end; i++) {            // use "let" in this line
     setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(i);
     }, 800);
 }
```

Comment: ok it work but if i want to set timeout acordingly ..How i shoul do that ? For example i want to put each number and delay number*800, if you simply add i*800 it delay 1 sec in every loop change.

Comment: @alexeyb - You use the argument named `index`.   See the second example I added to my answer.

Comment: Added ES6 example with `let` since that's the "modern" way to solve this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this to not to work, is because, of the `setTimeout` which is set to run after `800` and the scope of `i`.

By the time it executes which the value of `i` will already have changed. Thus no definitive result could be received. Just like TJ said, the way to work this around is through a handler function.

```
function handler( var1) {
    return function() {
      console.log(var1);  
    }        
}

var end = 8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i++) {     
   setTimeout(handler(i), 800);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jnGUd/)

Answer (score -2):

`setTimeout` accepts variables as additional arguments:

```
setTimeout(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
  }, 1000, 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

EDIT: In your example, the effective value of `i` will likely be `8`, since the function is merely to be called after the loop has finished. You need to pass the current value of `i` for each call:

```
var end=8;
for (var i = 1; i < end; i ++) {
  setTimeout(function (i) {
      console.log(i);   
   }, 800, i);
}
```

Comment: keep in mind though that "**Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.**"

Comment: You could always use the old (but deprecated) syntax for IE: `setTimeout('callable(' + i + ')', 1000);`.

Comment: This doesn't even work in **IE9**, much less earlier versions. This answer might be useful sometime in 2018 or so.